# My site crashes Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

When I try to open my site on IE (development, environment, or online), it crashes every time. This is my server readout upon entering the home page (it actually crashes on any page view after this):

`Rendered shared/_footer.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/index (179.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 204ms (Views: 203.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2010-10-24 03:16:26] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection 
was aborted by the software in your host machine.
C:/San/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in 'eof?'
C:/San/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in 'run'
C:/San/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in 'block in 
start_thread'`

Another error I sometimes get:

`[2010-10-24 03:22:21] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was 
forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Do you know what the problem might be? This is crucial for me because of the people who may be using the app. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What happens to internet explorer when you open the page? it hangs?

Comment: Without knowing other details, it is hurd to tell. But I would guess it is some JavaScript crashing the webbrowser. You should try to isolate the issue by disabling/removing javascript from your page. Then you can try to save an offline html version of the page and try opening that in IE from a local file to see if it crashes because of some HTML processing. Another issue could be faulty HTTP implementation on the server.

Comment: The error message is: Internet Explorer has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Options: Close Program. I usually have to force Windows to close IE at that point.

Comment: Could also be something with you CSS files. Not long ago I read about some tricks that was known to crash MSIE.

Comment: Marek - I'll take out some javascript and see what works there. Thanks for that idea. I'll get back to you if I find anything using this method.

Comment: Examples of how to crash msie: http://seo2.0.onreact.com/top-7-ways-to-crash-internet-explorer

Comment: Try to find the cause of the crash by going back to the barest minimum of the site that does work/load. E.g. only the application layout without the yield. And then, piece by piece, add parts until it crashes again.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I'm running into similar problems and looking for direction on solving it.